# Is there a way to use pause in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, animation, scheduling

Is there a way to do any similar to

```
Do[Print["Iteration...", j]; Pause[1], {j, 1, 6}]
```

with `Manipulate`? (to show the evolution of each iteration slowly)

What I have viewed is all with `Table`, and all the data is showed without no pause.

Using `Pause[1]` or wating for `"click a button or to press any key"`.

I was trying

```
Manipulate[Do[Print["Iteration...", j];   Pause[1], {j, 1, 6}],
           {{k, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}]
```

or similar things with `Row`, `Column`, `Style`,... but... no success!

Comment: Take a look at `ScheduledTasks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is support for variable rate animation built into `Manipulate`. Here is a very simple example. It may not be exactly what you want, but it might inspire you.

```
 Manipulate[Row[{"Iteration...", k}], {{k, 5}, 1, 8, 1}]
```

It will initially look like this

[image: initial]

but if you click on the [+] button the right of the slider you will get a set of animation controls, which you can use automatically run the control over its  range ofvalues. Further, you can adjust the rate.

[image: running]

Comment: Yes, yor solution is good for me. It´s needed to repeat all calculos from the start, but.... it´s suitable for me, in this way Manipulate[a = Table["Iteration...", {j, 1, k}]; b = Table[jk, {jk, 1, k}]; Print[b]; 
 Column[{TableForm[Transpose[{a, b}]]}], {{k, 5}, 1, 18, 1}]  --------------- The only problem is to use iterations where using Random, because in each computations change the values in the previous iterations and it´s impossible to follow the proccess. iteration by iteration. ------- I close the post but, if anyone has a solution, pease, comment it. Meanwhile I´m viewing Schedule..